# Bind input field to list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to create a form which has a TextAreaFor email addresses.  There are email addresses stored in a database.  I want these stored addresses to be the default value of the field, and then allow the user to add or remove addresses from the list as they see fit.

My viewModel;

```
public List<string> EmailAddresses { get; set; }
```

My View:

```
<%= Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.EmailAddresses) %>
```

(this is wrong, as it displays `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]` in the input field rather than each item in the list.

I know I can iterate through the list and display a separate textbox for each element in the list, but I want each element to be listed in a single textArea. (similar to an actual email client in that you can enter multiple addresses separated by a comma or semi) Is this possible?
I've searched, but have not found this scenario, which seems odd, because I think it must not be uncommon.
I'm thinking the solution may be to write a custom editorTemplate, but I'm hoping for a simpler solution.

Comment: how about <%= Html.TextAreaFor(m => string.Join(",", m.EmailAddresses.ToArray());) %>

Comment: @Asdfg That did not make for a happy compiler:), even after removing the extra ; ... thanks, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend you view model like so.

**View Model**
    public class PeopleViewModel {

```
    public List<string> EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public string EmaiAddressString {
        get {
            string rValue = string.Empty;
            EmailAddress.ForEach(x => rValue += (x + "\n" ));
            return rValue;
        }
        set {
            var newValue = value.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList<string>();
            EmailAddress = newValue;
        }

    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model SigKoExample.Models.PeopleViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
@if (IsPost) {
    <h2>New Values</h2>
    @Html.TextArea("EmailAddresses", Model.EmaiAddressString.ToString())
} else {
    using (Html.BeginForm()) { 
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.EmaiAddressString)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />                               
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    PeopleViewModel model = new PeopleViewModel {
        EmailAddress = new List<string> {
            "ValueOne",
            "ValueTwo"
        }
    };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(PeopleViewModel model) {
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: perfect answer. I didn't accept it at first because I got some goofy error, then I realized it was my fault, not yours:)  Thanks @anAgent!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a listboxfor in MVC instead of the text area. This way you can select individual entries in the list and either edit, delete, or add to that list by clicking a button and redirecting to another page or having the textbox you'd like to add on the same page. Check out this example. http://www.aspnetmvcninja.com/views/asp-net-mvc-select-list-example

Also if you'd like to input a large amount into a single test area and then add to the list then try using a TryParse on the "," to separate the email addresses. Then add them to the list.

Comment: Thanks @Clay.  Not exactly what I pictured, but it works and fills the requirement.  'preciate it!